# How can i get index of all the greatest elements in a nested list or matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Below code is a possible solution to my problem but I am interested in doing this without *numpy* or any other *python lib*.

*Input*
`[[20, 1], [20, 7], [1, 9]]`

*Expected Output*
`[(0, 0), (1, 0)]`

```
import numpy as np

matrix = [[20, 1], [20, 7], [1, 9]]

arr2D = np.array(matrix)
result = np.where(arr2D == np.amax(arr2D))
listOfCordinates = list(zip(result[0], result[1]))
print(listOfCordinates)
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What's your **specific** question?

Comment: On competitive portals we cant really use libraries, So I was interested in the algorithm and how it can be done in python

Comment: Well, that is still no question. We answer questions here. They have to be specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This here should work:

```
matrix = [[20, 1], [20, 7], [1, 9]]

max_n = matrix[0][0]
result = []
for row in range(len(matrix)):
    for col in range(len(matrix[0])):
        if matrix[row][col] == max_n:
            result.append((row, col))
        elif matrix[row][col] > max_n:
            max_n = matrix[row][col]
            result = [(row, col)]

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient solution but helps

```
matrix = [[20, 1], [20, 7], [1, 9]]
xIndex = []
yIndex = []
maxValues = []
cord = []
finalCord = []
finalMaxIndex = []

for i in range(len(matrix)):

    xIndex.append(i)
    maxSublist = max(matrix[i])
    yIndex.append(matrix[i].index(maxSublist))

for i, j in zip(xIndex, yIndex):

    cord.append((i,j))
    maxValues.append(matrix[i][j])
    maxValue = max(maxValues)

for i in range(len(maxValues)):

    if maxValue == maxValues[i]:
        finalMaxIndex.append(i)
    else:
        pass

for i in finalMaxIndex:
    finalCord.append(cord[i])

print('Index of multiple greatest elements in nested list or matrix:', finalCord)
```

```
matrix = [[20, 1], [20, 7], [1, 9]]
output = [(0, 0), (1, 0)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the max value of the list of lists first and then find the position of the elements whoe value is equal to the max value using a list comprehension

```
>>> lst = [[20, 1], [20, 7], [1, 9]]
>>> m = max(e for sub_lst in lst for e in sub_lst)
>>> [(i, j) for i,sub_lst in enumerate(lst) for j,e in enumerate(sub_lst) if e==m]
[(0, 0), (1, 0)]
```